# User clicks on forgot password links ends up logging into application if some other user is logged in on same browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise for authentication and using devise's default forgot password flow. When user clicks on forgot password link `http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=F1XrgcSTYs5nssRZrLqf`  then the user logs into application if some other user is already logged into the application on same browser. I understand It happens because devise checks `@current_user` in session and `@current_user` is the one who is logged in application on that browser.

How can I change the behaviour, User who clicks on forgot password should not login and should be redirected to reset password page.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails-3` **and** `ruby-on-rails-4`? Which version are you actually using? (It doesn't really make a difference to the answer in this case, but it's still misleading to tag as a multiple versions.)

Comment: I'm confused why you want this behaviour. Why would you want the user to be **logged out** when they click the "forgotten password" link? This is not normal behaviour of websites - for example, notice that you remain logged in when opening this link in a new tab: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: It's also fundamentally not how browsers work, for a user to be logged in on one tab, and logged out on another tab. (Or similarly, to be simultaneously logged in as two different users, in different tabs). You can achieve this with multiple browsers, or an incognito session, but not with two tabs.

Comment: it's not a bug, this the way a browser work, Instead of localhost try with ur IP  eg: 192.169.3.10:3000 to get another session in the same browser.